# How to determine if a JSON key has been set to null or not provided

Tags: java, json

I am using gson to convert JSON to my POJO. If I am not passing a specific parameter (the whole parameter, not just the value) in my JSON, it is automatically initialized as null. 
Is there a way to find out difference between the above null and the null I get, when I am passing that parameter value as null.

P.S. I cannot change the default conversion from JSON to POJO

Comment: not passing a specific parameter means passing "" ? or passing "{}" ?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? Won't the result be the same anyway?

Comment: @xxy I think he means like having fields "foo" and "bar" and only passing `{"foo":"foo"}` (no `bar`)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Not passing that field means:
{
    'title': 'ComputingandInformationsystems',
    'id': 1,
    'children': 'true'  
}
In the above JSON, two cases:

Case 1: Not passing:
{
    'id': 1,
    'children': 'true'  
}

Case 2: Passing null
{
    'title': null,
    'id': 1,
    'children': 'true'  
}

Comment: @Phil: I need to know them, as both the scenarios are different and I need to handle them differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use default value in your classes. When the field not pass in json string the value will be the default. example code like below.

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String age="not set";

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}

public class GsonClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String usersJson = "[ { \"name\": \"henry\" }, { \"name\": \"justin\",\"age\":null } ]";
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        User[] usersWithAge = gson.fromJson(usersJson, User[].class);
        for (User user : usersWithAge) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }
    }
}
```

output is here

```
User{name='henry', age=not set}
User{name='justin', age=null}
```

Comment: Ohh! How can I forget this... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys(theObject) will contain the key if the value is set to null or undefined.  Also theObject.hasOwnProperty(...) will let you know.

So convert the JSON to an object and inspect the keys to see if the value was marshalled as undefined, null, or not present.